# Order array of objects into every possible sequence in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

Wondering if there is a clean way of doing this in Swift. Maybe using one or a couple of the global functions, ie Map / Reduce etc

The array contains unique custom objects of **n** quantity.

For example, with 3 items. But could have more or less. **[1,2,3]**

Would return an Array of Arrays

**[
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
]**

[Here is a way in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132877/order-array-in-every-possible-sequence) to complete the task. Just need to get into Swift form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/JadenGeller/5d49e46d4084fc493e72

He created structs to handle permutations:

```
var greetingPermutations = PermutationSequenceGenerator(elements: ["hi", "hey", "hello"])
while let greetingSequence = greetingPermutations.next(){
    for greeting in greetingSequence {
    print("\(greeting) ")
   }
   println()
}
```

or:

```
var numberSpace = PermutationSpaceGenerator(objects: Array(1...4))
while let numberArray = numberSpace.next() {
   println(numberArray)
}
```

**EDIT**:

Here is a simpler way found on objc.io

**Add Extension**

```
extension Array {
    var decompose : (head: T, tail: [T])? {
        return (count > 0) ? (self[0], Array(self[1..<count])) : nil 
    }
}
```

**Add outside your extension / and class**

```
infix operator >>= {}
func >>=<A, B>(xs: [A], f: A -> [B]) -> [B] {
    return xs.map(f).reduce([], combine: +)
}
```

**Normal Class Functions**

```
func between<T>(x: T, ys: [T]) -> [[T]] {
    if let (head, tail) = ys.decompose {
        return [[x] + ys] + between(x, ys: tail).map { [head] + $0 }
    } else {
        return [[x]]
    }
}


func permutations<T>(xs: [T]) -> [[T]] {
    if let (head, tail) = xs.decompose {
        return permutations(tail) >>= { permTail in
            self.between(head, ys: permTail)
        }
    } else {
        return [[]]
    }
}
```

**Testing**

```
    let example = permutations([1,2,3,5,6,7,8])
    println(example)
```

This code extends Array with decompose function and also adds >>== operator (flattening) More about flattening: http://www.objc.io/snippets/4.html

Comment: what is between in: between(head, permTail)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to paste between function

Answer (score 2):

Probably too c-ish, but here is an alternative to the already posted examples.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var b = [[Int]]()

func perms<T>(n: Int, inout a: [T], inout b: [[T]]) {
    if n == 0 {
        b.append(a)
    } else {
        for i in 0..<n {
            perms(n - 1, &a, &b)
            var j = 0
            if n % 2 == 0 {
                j = i
            }
            swap(&a[j], &a[n - 1])
        }
    }
}


perms(a.count, &a, &b)
println(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

Updated version of @DogCoffee for swift 5.x, all within an array extension :

```
extension Array {
    private var decompose : (head: Element, tail: [Element])? {
        return (count > 0) ? (self[0], Array(self[1..<count])) : nil
    }
    
    private func between<T>(x: T, ys: [T]) -> [[T]] {
        if let (head, tail) = ys.decompose {
            return [[x] + ys] + between(x: x, ys: tail).map { [head] + $0 }
        } else {
            return [[x]]
        }
    }
    
    private func permutations<T>(xs: [T]) -> [[T]] {
        if let (head, tail) = xs.decompose {
            return permutations(xs: tail) >>= { permTail in
                self.between(x: head, ys: permTail)
            }
        } else {
            return [[]]
        }
    }
    
    func allPermutations() -> [[Element]] {
        return permutations(xs: self)
    } 
}

infix operator >>=
func >>=<A, B>(xs: [A], f: (A) -> [B]) -> [B] {
    return xs.map(f).reduce([], +)
}
```